# How do I find POS of \$F(X,Y,Z) = XY \oplus YZ \oplus 1\$

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do I find POS of \$F(X,Y,Z) = XY \oplus YZ \oplus 1\$?

Well I got to \$XY \oplus \overline Y \overline Z\$.

I remember I need to do something among the lines of \$XY(Z+\overline Z) \oplus (X + \overline X)\overline Y \overline Z\$.

Or maybe I thought about puting the function on a karnaugh map and finding the minterms of the SOP, and then the POS is trivial.

What's the best approach? how do I solve it?

Note: The solution started with \$F = (x + \overline y + \overline z)(\overline x + \overline y +z)\$. And then, it was quickly solved. but how did they get to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the thing to remember is that anything \$\oplus 1\$ is simply inverted.

```
 A B | O
-----+---
 0 0 | 0  \_ B XOR 0
 0 1 | 1  /
-----+---
 1 0 | 1  \_ B XOR 1
 1 1 | 0  /
```

So you immediately simplify the equation down to:

$$F(X,Y,Z) = XY \oplus (YZ \oplus 1) = XY \oplus \overline{YZ}$$

Which is what you got. But, you could equally simplify it another way:

$$F(X,Y,Z) = (XY \oplus YZ) \oplus 1 = \overline{XY \oplus YZ}$$

Which is an XNOR gate.

In fact you can turn an XOR gate into an XNOR gate by using an odd number of inverters:

$$\overline{XY \oplus YZ} \equiv \overline{XY} \oplus YZ \equiv XY \oplus \overline{YZ} \equiv \overline{\overline{XY} \oplus \overline{YZ}}$$

Comment: This is brilliant: \$\overline{XY \oplus YZ}\$ Thank you sir. !! (I managed solving it another way, a much longer one then with \$XY \oplus \overline {YZ}\$ but good to know that I can actually XOR the whole \$\overline{XY \oplus YZ}\$ instead of just what I did.